# Algorithm to minimize no of bin with maximum no of complete bin in 1D bin packing

Tags: algorithm, packing, bin-packing

I have to find the minimum number of bin required for a given set with maximum no of complete bins, I used First Fit Decreasing (FFD) for this but not satisfied with result.

For example, I have array `a=[3 4 3 4]`. On sorting I get `B=[4 4 3 3]`. Maximum size of bin is 10. Using FFD I get two no of bin with (4,4) and (3,3) as elements.

But I need to get result such that output should be (4,3,3) and (4) so that there will be maximum no of complete bin. I used Best fit Decreasing (BFD) but got same result.

What is the algorithm for this?

Comment: Just curious who is upvoting these low quality questions.

Comment: Please be more specific on the desired result. FFD is a heuristic, more precisely an inexact algorithm with an asymptotic approximation ratio. I find it surprising that you aim at maximizing the number of complete bins instead of minimizing the numer of total bins. Furthermore, your example seems to be wrong - it is impossible for FFD to generate more than one bit which is less than 50% filled.

Comment: Both the bins are more than 50% filled.Maximum size of each bin is 10 here

Comment: First of all i need to find the minimum no of bins,At that no of bins,i can have different combination.I need to find a combination such that complete bin should more

Comment: Actually i need to cut some rod in different pieces,Maximum size of my cutting machine is limited(ie,10 in this problem),The left over rod can be reused,So for reusing the left over, left over sholud be in one bin instead of spreading in multiple bin.Hence I dont want incomplete bin.Ie Want  4cm in one bin instead of 1 cm in 4 bin.

Comment: @Half-Bloodprince It is still not clear. Please extend your question: add examples of input and expected output, add more details about the task.